# Packer custom image build failed with ssh authentication error

Tags: packer

I'm trying to build custom image for AWS EKS managed node group, Note: my custom image (ubuntu) already has MFA and private key based authentication enabled.

I cloned github repository to build eks related changes from the below url.

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami && cd amazon-eks-ami
```

Next i made few changes to run the make file

```
cat eks-worker-al2.json
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_region": "eu-central-1",
    "ami_name": "template",
    "creator": "{{env `USER`}}",
    "encrypted": "false",
    "kms_key_id": "",
    "aws_access_key_id": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
    "aws_session_token": "{{env `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`}}",
    "binary_bucket_name": "amazon-eks",
    "binary_bucket_region": "eu-central-1",
    "kubernetes_version": "1.20",
    "kubernetes_build_date": null,
    "kernel_version": "",
    "docker_version": "19.03.13ce-1.amzn2",
    "containerd_version": "1.4.1-2.amzn2",
    "runc_version": "1.0.0-0.3.20210225.git12644e6.amzn2",
    "cni_plugin_version": "v0.8.6",
    "pull_cni_from_github": "true",
    "source_ami_id": "ami-12345678",
    "source_ami_owners": "00012345",
    "source_ami_filter_name": "template",
    "arch": null,
    "instance_type": null,
    "ami_description": "EKS Kubernetes Worker AMI with AmazonLinux2 image",
    "cleanup_image": "true",
    "ssh_interface": "",
    "ssh_username": "nandu",
    "ssh_private_key_file": "/home/nandu/.ssh/template_rsa.ppk",
    "temporary_security_group_source_cidrs": "",
    "security_group_id": "sg-08725678910",
    "associate_public_ip_address": "",
    "subnet_id": "subnet-01273896789",
    "remote_folder": "",
    "launch_block_device_mappings_volume_size": "4",
    "ami_users": "",
    "additional_yum_repos": "",
    "sonobuoy_e2e_registry": ""
```

After adding user and private key build getting failed with below error.

logs

```
amazon-ebs: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain.
```

Answer (score 0):

for me just changue region for aws o delete aws region in packer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30011812)